# Qunit + JSCoverage + Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, qunit, jscoverage

I have started using Qunit to test my JS code. I am looking into JSCoverage to generate the coverage reports later. We have a CI server (Jenkins) which already do a few things with our PHP code and I was wondering if anyone can comment on how I can integrate the report from my Qunit and JSCoverage into Jenkins

Thanks
Sparsh

Comment: For QUnit/Jenkins you can use the Arquillian-QUnit extension as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756644/jenkins-qunit/18263488#18263488

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QUnit: use [QUnit API](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit#Integration_into_Browser_Automation_Tools) to generate [junit XML](http://windyroad.org/2011/02/07/apache-ant-junit-xml-schema/) files. [Here's a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925847/1178189).

In *Post-build Actions* for your job you then check *Publish JUnit test result report* and specify your junit XML files (or their file pattern). Jenkins will then mark builds that have failed tests as unstable and produce a nice trend graph of successful/failing tests.

Comment: Any luck with getting coverage reports via JSCoverage?

Comment: The documentation on the QUnit API doesn't have clear steps that translate a QUnit .html file that runs on a browser to an automated, JUnit XML-generating Jenkins operation. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A few more details, for those actually attempting this:

## Putting together QUnit and Jenkins

If you want to run QUnit and publish the results in Jenkins, you'll need to do the following:

### Step 1: Getting QUnit to generate an XML file compatible with JUnit.

- If you're using Apache Ant, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275476/running-qunit-tests-with-jenkins-and-apache-ant) explains how to get
  QUnit to generate XML.
- If not, you can use Grunt and
  [grunt-qunit-junit](https://github.com/sbrandwoo/grunt-qunit-junit), together with [grunt-contrib-qunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit), to
  run your .html tests.
- And if you're not into either Ant or Grunt, [here](http://www.cameronjtinker.com/post/2013/09/24/QUnit-JSCoverage-and-Jenkins.aspx) is
  a script for PhantomJS to run your tests directly and produce
  JUnit-style XML.

### Step 2: Processing that XML file

This is the easy step - look in "Post-build Actions" for your job in Jenkins, and add the path to the XML file.