# Running QUnit tests served from an external web server with Karma

Tags: testing, qunit, karma-runner

My app is a Java webapp (*.war) which has a bunch of tests that are written in QUnit. They don't run automatically. What I do right now when I want to run the tests is the following:

1. Open the browser I want to test in
2. Surf to `http://localhost:8080/app/tests/index.html`

This `tests/index.html` file includes everything that is necessary to run the tests (e.g. AngularJS, QUnit, and my tests).

Now, what I want to do is run my tests in a more automated fashion. I have tried using Karma, setting it up like this (`karma.conf.js`):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['qunit'],
    proxies: {
        '/': 'http://localhost:8080/app/tests/index.html'
    },
    files: [],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

However, when I start Karma (by executing `karma start` in my app's directory) and surf to `http://localhost:9876/`, it doesn't seem to work. The output in `test-results.xml` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5)" package="" timestamp="2013-10-14T15:30:01" id="0" hostname="dhcp-255-11" tests="0" errors="1" failures="0" time="0">
    <properties>
      <property name="browser.fullName" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"/>
    </properties>
    <system-out><![CDATA[
]]></system-out>
    <system-err/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that Karma wants to serve the test files from disk, but I am not sure. Besides, it seems that simply serving the tests from an external host should not be a problem? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ant to build your project you are in luck. There is an ant task which uses the phantom headless browser to run qunit tests. Worked for me.

https://github.com/philmander/ant-jstestrunner

Also see this SO question

[Running QUnit tests with Jenkins and Apache Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275476/running-qunit-tests-with-jenkins-and-or-apache-ant)

However in my case we just switch our build process to use maven and I haven't got that working yet. Should be trivial to write a maven ant runner goal to do the same thing.

Comment: I am using Maven to build, and I'm afraid PhantomJS isn't good enough since my app uses localStorage and IndexedDB extensively. For this reason, I need a real browser environment. I was planning on solving this using BrowserStack. I will keep looking into this during the day however, and post any findings in this thread. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I look forward to your findings, vrutberg